# how to insert text(<textarea> to <p>) with js

Tags: javascript

How can I inject text from a `textarea` into a `p` element, using JavaScript?

I have got as far as the code you see below.

```
  <button id="btn" onclick="show()">click</button>
  <textarea placeholder="text..." id="textarea"></textarea>
  <p id="sp"></p>
  <script>
    function show() {

        var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
        var p = document.getElementById("sp");
        var text = document.createTextNode(textarea.innerHTML);
        p.appendChild(text);//insert to textarea
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: use document.getElementById("textarea").value or using JQuery $('#Textarea').val(''");

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var text = document.createTextNode(textarea.innerHTML);
> ```

The `innerHTML` of an element represents the child nodes inside it. For a textarea they set the **default** value.

To get the **current** value you need to read the `value` property instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code sample.get the value from textarea using  `textarea.value` and assign it as the content of p tag using  `p.textContent=text;`

```js
    function show() {

        var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
        var p = document.getElementById("sp");
        var text =textarea.value;
        p.textContent=text;
    }
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="show()">click</button>
<textarea placeholder="text..." id="textarea"></textarea>
<p id="sp"></p>
```

Comment: Why? What have you changed? Why should it make a difference? Please express your answer in the form of an answer and not as a game of spot-the-difference.

Comment: @Quentin I made some changes in my answer.i don't know how to explain more.I think the example is working